# Replace string in file with content in text box JAVA/ANDROID

Tags: java, android, textbox, replace

I've been doing some experiments with "replaceall" function to change content of a file. But Im wondering if it possible to replace a string with text taken from text box.

Example:

```
File:

NAME: JOHN DOE
GRADES:BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH

NAME: JOHN DOE
GRADES2: BLAH BLAH BLAH

NAME: JOHN DOE
GRADES3:BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

Then I would like to type in a textbox another "NAME" to replaceALL **"JOHN DOE's"** with for example: **"HULK HOGAN"**

```
EXPECTED RESULT:
```

File:

```
NAME: HULK HOGAN
GRADES:BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH

NAME: HULK HOGAN
GRADES2: BLAH BLAH BLAH

NAME: HULK HOGAN
GRADES3:BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

Is this possible???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is completely possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Eg (assuming you have a `TextView` with id `textView`)

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView);
String text = t.getText().toString();
String replaced = text.replaceAll (/*your implementation*/);
t.setText (replaced);
```

Same approach for `EditText`s

Comment: Hey! Thanks! this one did the trick. I merged it with a "button" to launch the "replacement" and save the changes into a new file, but when it is pressed the "file content" gets copied inside the textbox. Is there a way to solve this? (The "saving" part works properly)

Comment: If your approach is same as what I outlined, omit `t.setText (replaced);`. If the text gets auto-set every time you update that file, you should keep a copy of the old text in a separate `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just get the old string, and put it into the new.

```
TextView tv; //Get the pointer to the textbox, included for definition
String text=tv.getText();
tv.setText(text.replaceAll(....));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with something like this:

```
String myName = myEditText.getText().toString();
myText.replaceAll("John Doe", myName);
```